# How can I insert keyword "and" into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a bunch of values into a table I have created; the column is a varchar(100) and the values have the keyword "and" in them and it keeps throwing an syntax error on the first and in the list. Is it possible to have "and" as a value? This is a small sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
insert into groupings --Table Name
(variables) --Column
values (0 and .21875and 0 and 55 and 0 and 120 and 0 and 10000,)
0 and .21875and 0 and 55and 0 and 120and 10000.01 and 20000,
0 and .21875and 0 and 55and 0 and 120and 20000.01 and 30000,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need quotes around the value:

```
insert into groupings --Table Name
(variables) --Column
values ('0 and .21875and 0 and 55 and 0 and 120 and 0 and 10000',)
'0 and .21875and 0 and 55and 0 and 120and 10000.01 and 20000',
'0 and .21875and 0 and 55and 0 and 120and 20000.01 and 30000',)
```

As a note, I can't see this being a very good strategy for actually storing data, although I don't know what you're doing. I'd look into normalizing tables and doing a one-to many mapping. Or at least encoding your data into json or something standard. It'll make things easier for you in the future.

Comment: I tried that and for some reason the single quote still shows the error. And to be honest it is a very duct tape and terrible fix. I'm trying to run a stored procedure over and over with these values as parameters for it. There are 1000 values, so i need the procedure to run 1000 times and this was the first thing I thought of; get those parameters into a table and loop through it.

Comment: Actually man after refreshing my cache the query started working. Not really sure why but thanks I appreciate your help!